# "Description to follow"

Tags: grammaticality

My co-worker sent me a message with the text below:

> "description to follow"

Actually this is the only text inside of the message where there are some pictures attached.

I got what it says "Description will follow" or similar to that but what I want to learn is which grammar rule can explain this type of usage?

Comment: If you are going to mark all questions for close, then how are we supposed to ask questions? This votes to close are harming the usefulness of the website.

Comment: a downvote is not a vote to close. You don't have the 3k rep yet to be able to see real close votes

Comment: @simchona - I think people can see close votes on their own questions.

Comment: @matt not until a certain amount of rep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that "to follow" is the infinitive acting as an adjective, but think that the phrase is just shorthand for:

> [The] description [is going] to follow [this message].

The person who sent you the pictures did not have time to write out descriptions for them, nor did they have time to write the full sentence out.

"More to come" is a very common idiom.

Comment: Yep. There's nothing special about this, it's just that he omitted the words that could be inferred from context, as is acceptable in informal situations.